# dismiss the UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad in UIScrollView background

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uiscrollview, uikeyboard

I am dealing with what seems to be a somewhat rudimentary problem. I am trying to dismiss a `UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad` that has a `UIScrollView` background. I have seen some solutions that involve putting a done button where the decimal is if you have just a NumberPad. The problem is, I really need a decimal.

My next thought was to dismiss the keypad when the user touches the background, but since the background is a scroll view, I couldn't seem to connect an action to pick up a touch? One solution was to perhaps created a Custom Scroll View Controller...all of this seems a bit messy just to dismiss a keypad. Do I really have to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would it work for you if you put a `UIBarButtonItem` "Done" in your navigation bar?
Have you explored the `UITextField` property `inputAccessoryView`?

Comment: Ah! I just solved it using inputAccessoryView! Thank you so much. For those that want a good example, check out this link: http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.com/2011/05/input-accessory-view-how-to-add-extra.html

Comment: I found the above example overly complicated. Try this: http://pastebin.com/8kVEh1Du